# Два Activity и AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, activity, adapter

Помогите разобраться с логикой.

У меня есть первое `Activity`, в нем я создаю соединения с сервером, то есть вызываю `AsyncTask`. Теперь, в `AsyncTask` в случае успеха я создаю вторую `Activity`.

В нее мне нужно передать свой адаптер для `ListView`, и соответственно класс для отправки сообщений `DataOutputStream out`.

Как можно передать эти 2 класса? Или может стоит изменить логику? Но только уже решено что первая `Activity` создает подключения, вторая `Activity` отправляет данные. Ну а принимать будет `AsyncTask`

Не много добавлю. У меня такая задача:
Создается первая `Activity`, на ней скажем есть кнопка соединения.
Я нажимаю на кнопку соединения, и жду когда либо будет соединения с сервером, либо ошибка. Если соединения с сервером прошло успешно открывается другая `Activity` и начинает обмен сообщениями. Как это организовать?

Comment: Вам точно следует изменить логику, так как такие вещи передавать нельзя.

Comment: Я не много добавил, для наглядности, подскажите

Comment: Изменитие лучше логику на фрагменты. В активите можно иметь ссылку на фрагмент, которому в сеттер передать все, что надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 (второй) `Activity` лучше оставить отдельно.

Просто в функции `onProgressUpdate` в `AsyncTask` передайте первой активити что нужно вызывать 2й.  и Первая `Activity` будет вызывать 2го.

было бы легче ответить если показали бы кусок кода

**UPD:**

Создаете функцияю в первом `Activity` который вызывает 2е `Activity` (который передает ссылку `AsyncTask` в 2е `Activity`)

Результат `AsyncTask` передает на первый `Activity. Проверяете, если ответ положительный вызываете 2й`Activity` (через функцию)

Во втором `Activity` получаете `AsyncTask` и работаете дальше.

Comment: Я с низу дополнил вопрос.

Comment: я в intent Не могу ссылку на AsyncTask  передать

Comment: есть 2 примера как передавать `AsyncTask` на другой  `Activity` http://cyriltata.blogspot.com/2013/10/android-re-using-asynctask-class-across.html и http://stackoverflow.com/a/14370006/4953620

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать библиотеку AsyncHttpClient.Скачать можно отсюда:http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

На первом activity вызываете запрос на сервер, используя эту либу, при успехе результат придет в onSuccess, ошибка же придет в onFailure. Исходя из ответа, сами выберите что делать дальше, с данными. Передавать их в другую activity или же отобразить ошибку пользователю.